# Pause a procedure execution

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, firebird, sleep, firebird2.5

Programming languages like javascript and c# have ways to pause the current thread execution, with `sleep()`, `pause()`, etc.

How can I pause a Firebird procedure while it is running?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you want to pause the stored procedure?

Comment: you can make an infinite loop conditioned on something like `GEN_ID(generator_abused_as_barrier, 0) <> 0` - however it will not be "sleeping" while it would be "pausing", and indeed it would be against everything the database server engine expects of the database, so be very likie shooting yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than using `SUSPEND` as suggested by [user13964273](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13964273/user13964273), there is no way to pause execution or 'sleep' in Firebird PSQL itself. Using `SUSPEND` for sleep will only work with close cooperation with the application doing the fetching, so it is not actually a proper solution.

Firebird PSQL is not a general-purpose language. Wanting to pause within a stored procedure does not make much sense to me. Also, in SuperServer mode, actually sleeping (e.g. using UDF) within a stored procedure could - as far as I understand the inner-workings of Firebird - prevent other connections to the same database from doing work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUSPEND. It will pause the procedure execution till your next fetch from result set. Use SELECT FOR UPDATE to avoid server-side buffering.